# Tracking user metrics in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, analytics, metrics

What is a good way to keep track of the areas in an app that a user visits, or the features that he or she uses? I know there are several preexisting open-source frameworks:

[Google Analytics SDK for iOS](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/)

[iloggr analytics](http://code.google.com/p/iloggr-analytics/)

And I know that there are services such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) that also help. Does anyone know of any other options, and has anyone attempted to write a system that can keep track of some simple user metrics? A tutorial or example would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics has worked well for me. It's flexible enough that you can add tracking to pretty much everything. I have it set up in my application to track things such as view changes, which buttons are being pressed, issues encountered during media playback, and so on.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your usage? What do you mean by "issues encountered during media playback"?

Comment: hi j0k! If I want to track the user experience, like how much time is spent in a view, or which buttons are being pressed. Can I achieve this with Google Analytics?? Can I have a report by user? is there any API better to do this?  thanks